# Block access to robots.txt on HTTP only, in app.yaml

Tags: google-app-engine, yaml

I need to raise `404 Not Found` on `robots.txt`, while accessing from `HTTP`, on `HTTPS` `robots.txt` should be returned normally.

I couldn't find the way to restrict access to https only in `app.yaml` configuration, so I decided to write a handler for that, but got following error:

```
google.appengine.api.yaml_errors.EventError: Unexpected attribute "script" for mapping type static_files.
```

In `app.yaml` I have:

```
- url: /robots.txt
  script: main.application
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/robots.txt
```

What's the best way to handle such a situation?

Answer (score 0):

Simple handler will do:

app.yaml

```
- url: /robots_file
  static_files: static/robots.txt
  upload: static/robots.txt
```

views.py:

```
from google.appengine.api.urlfetch import fetch

class RobotsTxtHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def get(self):
        if self.request.url.startswith('https'):
            robots = fetch('{}/robots_file'.format(SITE_URL))
            return self.response.write(robots.content)
    raise errors.Http404
```

urls.py:

```
urls = [
   ('/robots.txt', views.RobotsTxtHandler),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Set `secure: always` in app.yaml for you handler.

Docs: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref

> `secure: always` - Requests for a URL that match this handler that do not use HTTPS are automatically redirected to the HTTPS URL with the same path. Query parameters are preserved for the redirect.

In your case:

```
- url: /robots.txt
  static_files: static/robots.txt
  upload: static/robots.txt
  secure: always
```

Comment: In my case it won't help, as crawlers are ignoring redirects, and they'll treat https/robots.txt as http/robots.txt.

Comment: If you need to make your site https only may be you should specify secure:always for all handlers and set canonical meta tag in HTML? You can check how I do it with http://DebtsTracker.io/